# Directly linking chrome web store extension in adwords campaign

Tags: google-chrome, google-ads-api, chrome-web-store

I'm doing some beta testing of my new Chrome extension for Gmail, and I'm wondering what the correct way to link to the web store from an adwords campaign is?

There isn't enough space to display the web store link, and shorteners violate policy. Should I be linking to the main site, and then using an ad extension with a link to the chrome store?

The idea is just to drive some limited targeted traffic directly to the download/install page without self hosting it yet.